# 301 redirect: Why connection close?

Tags: java, http, redirect, http-status-code-301

I learned to use `Connection: close` when doing 301 redirects in Java

```
response.setStatus(301);
response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.example.com/");
response.setHeader("Connection", "close");
```

Why do we do this? Why not omit the last line?

I have seen this in at least three examples, including this one: http://www.pardontheinformation.com/2010/09/java-servlet-jsp-301-and-302-redirect.html

I have never seen the last line omitted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your redirection points to a different server, the browser will have to use another connection anyway, so you're just giving the browser advance notice that it probably won't need to contact the *current* server again for this page. However, if your redirection points to the *same* server, I see no reason to close the connection.

Comment: Unless it points to the same server but... on a different port? e.g. http -> https redirect? Then it makes sense to close the connection, right?

Comment: @Patryk you bet. I'd go further to say that if it's over the same connection, just return the resource if that's possible rather than a URL pointing to the new location. It's less wasteful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the connection: close header in your redirect unless you are sure the connection won't be needed. That's because connections can often be reused especially in HTTP/2 which uses the same TCP connection for every hostname with the same IP address and port number.

For example if you are redirecting from https://example.com to https://www.example.com in HTTP/1, these would each require two different connections. But assuming they share the same server IP address, HTTP/2 will automatically reuse the same connection in the second request which saves overhead and time. (HTTP/2 also supports server push which means you could further speed things up by [pushing the new URL along with the redirect.](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/#you-can-push-items-for-other-origins))

HTTP/1.1 will also automatically reuse the connection if both the hostname and the port number are the same, like when redirecting from http://example.com to http://example.com/home/

I will also add that if you can just return the resource rather than returning a redirect that will be faster and you should just consider doing that along with a link header telling search engines where the [canonical URL](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls) is. That especially works well when the only thing different is the path, because then with a little bit of JavaScript you can also change the location bar to show the canonical URL with [History.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState). The effect is the same as a redirect without the overhead of a redirect.

I've literally never added connection: close to a redirect, but I could see doing it when you're sure the connection isn't needed anymore like when redirecting from http to https which will always require a new TCP connection.